# Vuejs swal alerts notification prompt

Tags: css, laravel, vue.js, frontend, software-design

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhYvO.png)Can someone help me I'm new in vuejs .how can i move this "okay" button to the right edge corner of the notification card. I've try many ways online but i cant move the okay button.

This is my code inside the method script

```
Swal.fire({
                title: "test2-e says",
                text: "Be sure to check correctness of all data before generating the report",
                confirmButtonText: "OK",
                position: "top",
                customClass: {
                    title: 'text-left', // Align the title to the left
                    confirmButton: 'text-right custom-ok-button', // Align the "OK" button to the right and add custom class
                    popup: 'custom-swal-popup', // Custom class for positioning at the top
                },
            }).then(result => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    console.log("OK button clicked");
                    this.retrieveData();
                }
            });
```

This is the style

```
.custom-ok-button {
    background-color: blue; // Set the background color to blue
    padding: 5px 10px; // Adjust padding as needed
}
.custom-swal-popup {
    top: 0;
}
```

I want to move the button to the right edge of the corne.

Answer (score 0):

The alignment of the button comes from its [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) parent wrapper (at least in the latest SweetAlert version), which you will have to configure.

For example:

```css
.swal2-actions{
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

<script>
Swal.fire({
  title: "test2-e says",
  text: "Be sure to check correctness of all data before generating the report",
  confirmButtonText: "OK",
  position: "top",
  customClass: {
      title: 'text-left', // Align the title to the left
      confirmButton: 'text-right custom-ok-button', // Align the "OK" button to the right and add custom class
      popup: 'custom-swal-popup', // Custom class for positioning at the top
  },
}).then(result => {
  if (result.isConfirmed) {
      console.log("OK button clicked");
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not using html template sir . where do I need to insert this? inside the <template> or <script method> or <style> 

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

and the swal2-actions is not present in my structure.